# Need of security rules in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase as backend for my android app. I recently came across database security rules. In my app, any user can access only some specific data to which I have created a DatabaseReference to, in the code of the app. So why do we need security rules if I specify the portions of data the user can access through the app, in the code itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your code can easily be changed to do whatever an attacker wants.  The rules one the server can't be changed or circumvented in any way, except by knowing how to log in to your Google account.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please tell me how the code of my app could be changed after uploading the app on the play store? Also, even if someone got hold of my app code, changed the code and created an apk, still, doesn't firebase allow only those apps to connect which were signed using the SHA1 key of the computer used to connect the app to the Firebase project? It would be very helpful if you could show me how the app could be cracked. Thanks.

Comment: It's a complicated issue and can't be explained in the space available of a Stack Overflow comment.  There are potentially many ways it could be done.  This is something you can research on your own.  The bottom line is that clients code is very possible to compromise, which means security should only be handled on the server.